# php create javascript in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php

i have the following code, but it will not work. i am trying to create a script output:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"><!--\n";
echo "SLIDES = new slideshow(\"SLIDES\")\n";

  // Now loop through the files, echoing out a new select option for each one
  foreach( $files as $fname ) {
    echo 's = new slide()\n';
    echo 's.src =  \"http://cashbackflorida.com/wpradmin/modules/wprrets/photos/'.$result ->MLS.'/'{$fname}\n\"';
    echo 's.width = \"560\"\n';
    echo 's.height = \"420\"\n';
    echo 's.alt = \"{$fname}\"\n';
    echo 's.text = unescape(\"\")\n';
    echo 's.link = \"\"\n';
    echo 's.target = \"\"\n';
    echo 's.attr = \"\"\n';
    echo 's.filter = \"\"\n';
    echo 'SLIDES.add_slide(s)\n';
  }

  echo '--></script>\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it this way.  Just output the array to JavaScript and deal with it there.

```
var files = <?php echo json_encode($files); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the problem in your string escaping

```
echo 's.height = \"420\"\n';
```

You can't escape in single quote strings like that. So try this

```
echo "s.height = \"420\"\n";
```

You do NOT need to escape single quotes within double quotes or visa versa, but you can only get a newline character like that in a double quote string.
I would recommend HEREDOC for this kind of string writing though.

```
$fnamej = json_encode($fname);
echo << EOT
s.height = "420";
s.alt = $fnamej;
EOT;
```

I am also inclined to say that you'd be better off handling this in javascript. This may end up behaving very badly all of a sudden, and it will take up more bandwidth.

Comment: You can't simply output the filename in JavaScript.  It needs to be escaped, which is the purpose of the JSON encoding in my answer.

Comment: We are in agreement @Brad, JSON is the way to go. A javascript function that handles the data in the client would be more stable than writing spaghetti code at runtime.
I just wanted to first clarify the big syntactical issues with the code in question.

Comment: You should use `json_encode()` in your code sample though.  People blindly copy/paste code from StackOverflow all the time without knowing the implications of it.

Comment: That would be answering a question that wasn't asked. It's ugly, but the code above works.

Comment: The code above doesn't work if the file name contains a character that must be escaped, such as a backslash on Windows.